# Custom Spring UserDetailsService not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, userdetailsservice

I'm trying to add some custom data for currently logged in user, so I found that I can implement my own UserDetailsService and just plug it in Spring, but it's never called, I always get Principal as just username string.

I have my implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    ...
  }
}
```

my implementation of UserDetails:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class LoggedInUser extends User {
...
}
```

and tried setting it in config (SecurityConfiguration) multiple ways:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      @Autowired
      private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;
      @Autowired
      private UserDetailsService userDetailServiceImpl;
      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordService.getPasswordEncoder());
      }
...
}
```

or

```
@Autowired
  protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordService.getPasswordEncoder());
  }
```

or

```
@Override
  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailServiceImpl();
  }
```

and nothing works... I tried retrieving user info multiple ways:

1. in controller with @AuthenticationPrincipal where I get null
2. in service (I get invalid cast error):

   Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   (LoggedInUser) authentication.getPrincipal()

Any idea why it's not working? Is my impl class being overriden by default one somewhere else? I tried to look in the logs (logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE) but no luck :/
I can login, that works fine, just principal data is always only username String and not my class.

Comment: did you secure your endpoints?

Comment: What is `CustomAuthenticationProvider`? Show your code.

Comment: Might be mistaken, but I think your userDetailsService is not called because you defined a custom authentication provider. It does the whole job inluding finding user.

Comment: @rbiggy could you please share your code, especially your security config? I'm struggling with the same issue: the CustomAuthenticationProvider does not work (the authenticate() method does not get called) and the UserDetailsService does not get called either..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ILya Cyclone's comment was what was the key to figuring out what was wrong, after checking `CustomAuthenticationProvider` again I noticed that when returning data you can specify `Principal` that does not need to be only username, but you can add your custom `UserDetails` there and because of that custom `UserDetailsService` is not called, which was my mistake in assuming that it will be always called.

So in the end this is enough to have custom `AuthenticationProvider` with custom `UserDetails`:

```
@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private PasswordService passwordService;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = auth.getName();
    String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();

    User user = userService.getUserWithPermissionsByName(username);
    if (user == null) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid_username_or_pass");
    }

    if (!passwordService.passwordsMatch(password, user.getPassword())) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid_username_or_pass");
    }

    String[] permissions = user.getPermissions().stream().map((p) -> p.getName()).toArray(String[]::new);
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(permissions);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new LoggedInUser(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, grantedAuths, user.getId()),
        password, grantedAuths);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
    return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know, but there's time limit, I need to wait for 20 more hours to be able to accept it